# Store C++ Array outside loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem when trying to tesselate a polygon using GLU. The vertex callback always calls back with the last vertex defined by gluTessVertex. It seems as though the values stored in GLdouble v[3] are getting GC'd in each iteration of the for loop. How can I store each GLdouble v[3] so it does not get GC'd?

```
for(int i = 0; i < vtxcnt; i++)
{
    float lon = dbls[i * 2];
    float lat = dbls[(i * 2)+1];
    GLdouble v[3] = {lon, lat, 0.0f};
    gluTessVertex(tess, v, v);
}
```

*** EDIT: This seems to fix the problem... ***

```
GLdouble *vtxs = new GLdouble[vtxcnt * 3];

for(int i = 0; i < vtxcnt; i++)
{
    lon = dbls[i * 2];
    lat = dbls[(i * 2)+1];

    vtxs[(i * 3) + 0] = (double)lon;
    vtxs[(i * 3) + 1] = (double)lat;
    vtxs[(i * 3) + 2] = (double)0;
    gluTessVertex(tess, &vtxs[(i * 3) + 0], &vtxs[(i * 3) + 0]);
}
```

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have a garbage collector at all.

Answer (score 1):

`gluTessVertex` only stores the vertex pointer. The pointer must stay valid until the tesselation is performed. This is not the case in your code, so it fails.